# compute SD and VAR for a time variable

Tags: r

How I am trying to compute SD and VAR for a difference in start and end times, its a time-variable basically, I get a NA when I run:

> hms::as_hms(var(hms::as_hms(samp.trips$ride_length)))
> NA

how can I get around this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add a tag specifying the programming language.

Comment: The programming language is R.

Comment: Please add `r` as a tag.